# How to use filter in list comprehension?

Tags: haskell, filter, list-comprehension

So i'm trying to make a setSubtraction from 2 set lists where it returns the set of all elements that occur in xs but not in ys.  For example xs = [1,2,3] and ys = [3,4,5], then setSubtraction xs ys =  [1,2]

this is what i have so far

```
setSubtract xs ys = [x | x <- xs, y <- ys, filter (==y) xs]
```

but the filter function seems to be erroring out

Comment: nevermind, i was able to figure it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed your code little bit, and filter `(== x)` `ys == []` checks that `x` does not appear in `ys`.

Here's the definition:

```
setSubtract xs ys = [x | x <- xs, filter ( == x) ys == []]
```

Here it is in action:

```
λ>  setSubtract [1,2,3] [3,4,5]
[1,2]
λ> setSubtract [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] [3,4,5]
[1,2,6,7]
λ>
```

An alternate definition

```
setSubtract xs ys = [x | x <- xs, not . any ( == x) $ ys]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 setSubtract cmp xs ys = [x | x <- xs, member cmp x ys == False]
```